# Is the unit circle in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets, borel-measures

Is the unit circle in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ ?

The definitions I am working with is that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$  is the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by open (equivalently closed, or clopen) rectangles. i.e sets of the form $(a_1,b_1) \times (a_2,b_2)$

**Approach 1:**

I think maybe I can get there in the limit of unions of lots and lots of rectangles. Here was my approach:

$S =(-1,1) \times (-1,1)$ and then we construct some kind of limit of squares to take away from the square, $S$, that leave us with just the circle?

**Approach 2:**

Consider $f:(\mathbb{R^2},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ by $f(x,y) = x^2 +y^2$

$f$ is clearly continuous and as such is Borel measurable. This means that the pre-image of any measurable set is measurable and hence $f^{-1}(0,1),$ the unit circle, is measurable?

Approach 2 *seems to be* correct but it feels too simple, are there any mistakes? Would approach 1 provide a fruitful answer?
Any help or even an alternative method of your own would be really helpful!

Happy holidays :)

Comment: The OP uses a lot of times the "unit circle", but at the end it seems to deal with the open unit disk. Usually, the unit circle $S^1$ inside $\Bbb R^2$ is the set of points $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2=1$. For the open disk the equation is $x^2 + y^2<1$. But the mentioned preimage via $f$ of $(0,1)$ is the punctured unit disk. Well, approach (2) works directly and is fine. Do we have any questions left now? If yes, please state them clearly. (Approach (1) is too pedestrian and not easy to be put on the paper...)

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you, and of course I will edit the question and refer to it as the open disk. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, I will try to make a visual proof, I will use the $\sigma-$alegbra generated by the closed rectangles, wich is the same as you said. Take the disk $B=B(0,1)$ now for $k\in \mathbb N$ imagine all the squares of the form $P_k=\{[n/2^k,(n+1)/2^k]\times[m/2^k,(m+1)/2^k]:m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ (this is like a grid of squares of length $1/2^k$) and define $A_k$ as the union of all the squares in $P_k$ that are contained in the disk. Since any square in $P_{k}$ can be written as the union of four squares in $P_{k+1}$ you have that $A_k\subset A_{k+1}$, you have that $B=\bigcup A_k$.

To proove this take any point $p$ in $B$, since $B$ is open there is a ball $B_p$ of radius $\varepsilon$ centered in $p$ and contained in $B$, now take $k$ such that $\frac{1}{2^k}<\varepsilon$, then $p$ belongs to a square of $P_{k+1}$ contained in $B_p$:

Take a square $S$ of $P_{k+1}$ containing $p$ (since $P_{k+1}$ covers all $R^2$ the existance of such square is guaranteed) for any point $x$ in $S$ you have that $$d(x,p)\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2^{k+1/2}}<\frac{1}{2^k}<\varepsilon$$
So $S\subset B_p\subset B$, hence for all $p\in B$ there exist $k$ such that $p\in A_k\subset B$.

Comment: You can use exactly this proof replacing $B$ for any open set and it will still hold, you can also use a similar proof for $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Fantastic Answer Matias! Thank you very much!